# Change url in foreach statement

Tags: php, foreach, preg-replace

We have some code that brings back image urls from an external source. We to modify the

```
<?php
$imagez = get_field('prop_gallery_images');
foreach($imagez as $image) {
    if($image['type']==0) {
        ?>
        <img src="<?=$image?>">
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Result:

```
<img src="http://www.externalsource.com/store/property/165+156_sm.jpg">
<img src="http://www.externalsource.com/store/property/165+158_sm.jpg">
<img src="http://www.externalsource.com/store/property/165+159_sm.jpg">
```

I want to change the url where it says _sm to _web as that bring in a higher resolution version of the image. I thought of using preg_replace but not sure how this would work in a foreach statement as I have not done that before? Also not sure if this is the cleanest way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You will have to provide the code where $image is created. Is it static? Or created with a concatenation?

Comment: I'm guessing `get_field` is a database wrapper and the image url is coming straight from the db. Question is do you want to store the 'better url' or the 'sm url' in the database. If the latter, then doing the simple `str_replace` as Lovepreet suggested will work fine.

Comment: Strictly speaking, storing the entire url is bad practice because you lose the ability to switch domains, or even use an SSL certificate (without getting mixed content warnings). You should just store the unique part, and then concatenate the rest. Now if you are looking for a quick win, Lovepreet's solution will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple by using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
<img src="<?= str_replace('_sm', '_web', $image);?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "clean" array to start with (e.g. to abstract the logic) then you can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). This function applies a user defined function to each element in an array.

```
<?php

$images = array(
  'http://www.externalsource.com/store/property/165+156_sm.jpg',
  'http://www.externalsource.com/store/property/165+158_sm.jpg',
  'http://www.externalsource.com/store/property/165+159_sm.jpg',
);

$highresImages = array_map(function($url) {
  return str_replace('_sm.', '_web.', $url);
}, $images);

print_r($highresImages);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.externalsource.com/store/property/165+156_web.jpg
    [1] => http://www.externalsource.com/store/property/165+158_web.jpg
    [2] => http://www.externalsource.com/store/property/165+159_web.jpg
)
```

https://eval.in/1035497